# The tag liferay-ui:include is missing on liferay 6.2

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.2-ee-sp1 and I am trying use liferay-ui:include. I need to use a page.jsp from the other jar file. I find out that it is possible with this tag, but I have some troubles with it. My jsp page looks like:

```
.
.
<%@taglib prefix="liferay-ui" uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" %>
. 
.
<liferay-ui:include page="/html/jsp/page.jsp" servletContext="<%=this.getServletContext() %>"/>
```

And when I start my liferay I will get this error:

```
No tag "include" defined in tag library imported with prefix "liferay-ui"
```

So I looked to the liferay-ui.tld and there is no include tag.

My question is: How can I find/import/include/use the liferay-ui:include tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no such tag in liferay ui taglib the one which is used for including a jsp page 
is available in 
taglib

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util" %>
```

and the tag for including a jsp page is

```
<liferay-util:include page="" servletContext=""></liferay-util:include>
```

where page attribute is the reference to a particular jsp and servletcontext takes the 
servlet context object as parameter

Comment: Thanks a lot, I dont know why I was so sure that it is in ui lib. My fault.

Comment: The liferay-ui taglib is valid. You can find tld in /portal-web/docroot/html/taglib/ui . Liferay use a lot this taglib to generate it user interface.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for <[liferay-util:include](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/taglibs/liferay-util/include.html)> (?)